# How do I make a long list print in segments?

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm trying to learn python by writing code I'm interested in, currently I want to list all of the primes up to a number of my choice at runtime.  However, when I print the primes they just all get blurted out on one line.  If you enter a big number this gets really really long.  How can I make it so that my print always does like 10 indices then starts a new line?

Note: this is extremely verbose just for debugging purposes.

My code:

```
primes = []
numberToGoTo = int(input("Find primes up to what number?\n"))

for i in range(2, numberToGoTo):
    for j in range(2, i):
        print("Checking to see if {} is a prime.  Current divisor: {}".format(i, j))
        if i % j == 0 and j > 1 and j < i:
            print("{} is not prime".format(i))
            break
    else:
        print("{} is a prime! Adding to list.".format(i))
        primes.append(i)
else:
    #number of primes
    print(len(primes))
    #list all primes
    print(primes)
```

Comment: Look into the `pprint` module

Comment: can you also add how you are expecting your output?

Comment: Sure!  Just like ten primes per line, then a new line with up to ten and a new line with up to ten, and so on until the end

Comment: @sshashank124 pprint worked great!

Comment: Awesome. Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

You can use create custom print function to do this.

```
def custom_print(primes, index):
    index /= 2
    lim = index
    while(lim <= len(primes)):
        print(primes[lim-index:lim+index])
        lim += index

custom_print(primes, 10)
```

I hope this helps.